# Why GregorianCalendar sets HOUR depending on System time(AM/PM)

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar, java.util.calendar

I am simply creating a java.util.GregorianCalender

```
GregorianCalendar calender = new GregorianCalendar();
```

now setting the hour,min,sec and ms as follows

```
c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 6);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45); 
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);         
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 345);
```

now printing the output using getTime() method

```
System.out.println("Date and Time: "+c.getTime());
```

When System time is in AM, the output is

```
Date and Time: Tue Feb 09 06:45:23 IST 2016
```

And When System time is in PM, the output is

```
Date and Time: Tue Feb 09 18:45:23 IST 2016
```

Now my question is why the output is changing with the system time?

Comment: @assylias I understand that

Comment: @ Jordi Castilla I think you did not get my question: I need to know the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new GregorianCalendar()` fields are set using the current time in your default time zone. The AM/PM flag is therefore set depending on whether the current time in your default time zone is AM or PM.

When you set `HOUR` to 6, the AM/PM flag is not changed and the resulting calendar is set on 6am or 6pm depending on the current time.

If you set `HOUR_OF_DAY` to 6, the calendar will be set on 6am, regardless of current time.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. Now I understand it. Could you please tell me if we set HOUR to 18(i,e greater than 11), then what is the expected behavior?

Comment: I don't think it is well defined but looking at the implementation it will use 18 as hour of day and add 12 if the AM/PM flag is on set to PM (resulting in 6AM the day after).

Comment: if it will use 18 as hour of day then why the question of AM/PM is coming?

Comment: Sorry I meant hour. Hour = 18 => hour of day = 18 + PM?12:0; => 30 if PM => 6am the next day. If that makes sense... But that seems
 to be an abuse of the API...